# How to get all available audio track from a video file in android

Tags: android, audio

I have one video file which have 3 audio track say English, Hindi and Russian.

I want to play all track simultaneously so for performing this task i want all embedded audio track as separate source on application layer.

I tried `mediaplayer.getTrackInfo()` but it only returns one track at a time.

Please suggest me if you have any idea regarding this concern.

Thanks in advance.